# MPI send receive

Tags: c, parallel-processing, tags, mpi, send

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];  {
int numtasks, rank, dest, source, rc, count, tag=1;
MPI_Status Stat;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank%2 == 1) {
dest = (rank+1)%numtasks;
  source = (rank-1+numtasks)%numtasks;
  rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag,MPICOMM_WORLD, &Stat);
}

else  {
  dest   = (rank-1+numtasks)%numtasks;
  source = (rank+1)%numtasks;
  rc = MPI_Recv(  &inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat );
  rc = MPI_Send( &outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest,   tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
}
rc = MPI_Get_count(&Stat, MPI_CHAR, &count);
printf("Task %d: Received %d char(s) from task %d with tag %d\n",
   rank, count, Stat.MPI_SOURCE, Stat.MPI_TAG);

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**Results:**

```
Task 2: Received 1 char(s) from task 3 with a tag 1
Task 0: Received 1 char(s) from task 1 with a tag 1
```

Why the task can't identify more than 2 processors?
I want run it on more than 2 processors.
I've updated the mpi program with the ring pattern, i think maybe wrong at the line if(rank%2==1)

Comment: Consider adding some more details with the question.

Comment: I'm afraid this question indicates that you have no understanding of the basics of MPI or programming itself. You should follow your course more closely. SO is not a replacement for teaching.

Answer (score 0):

`count` and `Stat` are only initialized on ranks 0 and 1, so you are basically printing garbage on ranks 2 and 3.

Your program is hard-coded to run on 2 tasks (it will crash on 1 task, and print garbage with 3 tasks or more).

I suggest you investigate using `MPI_Sendrecv()` in order to send and receive deadlock-free in one MPI call.

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, please elaborate and update your question. That being said, you might consider a ring pattern so your program can run on any number of MPI tasks (e.g. send to `(rank+1)%numtasks` and receive from `(rank+numtasks-1)%numtasks`)

Per your edited question, the communication pattern can the same for all the MPI ranks as follow

```
dest = (rank+1)%numtasks;
source = (rank-1+numtasks)%numtasks;
MPI_Sendrecv(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag,
             &inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag,
             MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
```

Comment: this might not answer the question strictly speaking, but it does explain the a priori ununderstandable output. i will be more than happy to update my answer based on user clarification.

Comment: Yes i try to use ring pattern, but maybe i put (rank+1)%numtasks at the wrong line of program, the results still error..

Comment: please update your question with the code for the ring pattern

Comment: or maybe issue a new question, since the problem is quite different now.

Comment: `dest` and `source` must have the same definition on all ranks (they are currently swapped on odd vs even ranks). then you can use `MPI_Sendrecv()` so you have a unique path regardless the rank.

Comment: What.! U are right... The dest and source must be same.. Thank you so much.!! I got the answer... ^_^ @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: Hye.! How can i reach you.? I want to ask something about MPI program..- @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: If this is about MPI programming, then you can ask a new question on SO. in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/8062491) you will find my twitter and GitHub accounts.

Answer (score 0):

### May try to better investigate the MPI mechanics:

Do not hesitate to experiment with the code, as it will help you grasp the concept of **`numtasks`**, **`rank`**-ID and associated run-time operations. Compilation errors will report shortcuts in the above posted code. For more MPI-related practices and insights, one ought also assign and evaluate **`rc`** return codes, from the respective `MPI_<fun>()`-calls

**Q:** Why the task can't identify more than 2 processors?
**A:** It **can,** but the `if(){..}else if(){..}` code-blocks did not allow others to produce any visible output.

**Q:** I want to change that 4197005 result into 2, 3 - how?
**A:** One cannot change an MPI-reported number, but you can change the behaviour of your code ( see below ) and make some more outputs, where feasible about **who** is doing **what**, **when**, **how** and **where** it is actually going on. This way we learn to understand the MPI-concepts and validate the actual MPI-code execution.

Feel free to ask more.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[]
          ) {
   int        numtasks, rank, dest, source, rc, count, tag = 1;
   MPI_Status Stat;

   printf( "(INF) will MPI_Init()...\n" );

   MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
   printf( "(INF)      MPI_Init() done.\n" );

   MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks );
   MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
   printf( "(INF) I am MPI[%d of %d]\n",
            rank,
            numtasks
            );

   if ( rank  == 0 ) {
        dest   = 1;
        source = 1;
        rc     = MPI_Send( &outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest,   tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
        rc     = MPI_Recv(  &inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat );
        printf( "(INF) I am MPI[%d of %d] having just completed an MPI_Send( ->MPI[%d] ) + MPI_Recv( <-MPI[%d] ). Last RetCODE == %d.\n",
                 rank,
                 numtasks,
                 dest,
                 source,
                 rc
                 );
   }
   else
   if ( rank  == 1 ) {
        dest   = 0;
        source = 0;
        rc     = MPI_Recv(  &inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat );
        rc     = MPI_Send( &outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest,   tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
        printf( "(INF) I am MPI[%d of %d] having just completed an MPI_Recv( <-MPI[%d] ) + MPI_Send( ->MPI[%d] ). Last RetCODE == %d\n",
                 rank,
                 numtasks,
                 source,
                 dest,
                 rc
                 );
   }
   else
   if ( rank  == 2 ) {
        dest   = 3;
        source = 3;
        rc     = MPI_Recv(  &inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat );
        rc     = MPI_Send( &outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest,   tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
        printf( "(INF) I am MPI[%d of %d] having just completed an MPI_Recv( <-MPI[%d] ) + MPI_Send( ->MPI[%d] ). Last RetCODE == %d\n",
                 rank,
                 numtasks,
                 source,
                 dest,
                 rc
                 );
   }
   else
   if ( rank  == 3 ) {
        dest   = 2;
        source = 2;
        rc     = MPI_Send( &outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest,   tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
        rc     = MPI_Recv(  &inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat );
        printf( "(INF) I am MPI[%d of %d] having just completed an MPI_Send( ->MPI[%d] ) + MPI_Recv( <-MPI[%d] ). Last RetCODE == %d\n",
                 rank,
                 numtasks,
                 dest,
                 source,
                 rc
                 );
   }
   else {
        printf( "(INF) I am MPI[%d of %d] will NOP...\n",
                 rank,
                 numtasks
                 );

   }
   rc = MPI_Get_count( &Stat, MPI_CHAR, &count );
   /*
            Task  3: Received  1 char(s) from task 4197005 with a tag 0
            Task  2: Received  1 char(s) from task 4197005 with a tag 0
            Task  1: Received  1 char(s) from task 0       with a tag 1
            Task  0: Received  1 char(s) from task 1       with a tag 1                        */
   printf( "Task %d: Received %d char(s) from task %d with tag %d\n",
            rank,
            count,
            Stat.MPI_SOURCE,
            Stat.MPI_TAG
            );

   printf( "(INF) I am MPI[%d of %d]: will MPI_Finalize()...\n",
            rank,
            numtasks
            );
   MPI_Finalize();

   printf( "(INF) I am MPI[%d of %d]:      MPI_Finalize() done, will exit()...\n",
            rank,
            numtasks
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main (argc,argv)
int argc;
char *argv[]; {
int numtasks, rank, dest, source, rc, count, tag=1;
char inmsg, outmsg='x';
MPI_Status Stat;

MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

if (rank%2 == 0)
{
dest=(rank+1)%numtasks;
source=(rank+1)%numtasks;

rc = MPI_Send(&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
rc = MPI_Recv(&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
}

else {
dest = (rank-1+numtasks)%numtasks;
source = (rank-1+numtasks)%numtasks;
rc = MPI_Recv (&inmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
rc = MPI_Send (&outmsg, 1, MPI_CHAR, dest,  tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

{
rc = MPI_Get_count (&Stat, MPI_CHAR, &count);
printf ("Task %d: Received %d char(s) from task %d with a tag %d \n", rank, count, Stat.MPI_SOURCE, Stat.MPI_TAG);
}
MPI_Finalize();
```

Comment: this will deadlock if you run an odd number of MPI tasks. Also, the pattern is not a ring but pairwise exchanges.